# Convert EncodedImage to Bitmap in Blackberry

Tags: image, blackberry, java-me, bitmap

I want to convert EncodedImage into Bitmap in Blackberry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("imahge.png");

Bitmap bitmap = encodedImage.getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BitmapField img = new BitmapField();
img.setImage(your encoded image); 
screen.add(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EncodedImage img=EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("Imagename");

Bitmap bitmap=img.getBitmap();
```